# How to install chromedriver with binman package on Mac

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, rstudio

I am trying to work with RSelenium and chromedriver on a Mac with an M2 chip. Since one of the last updates the combination of chrome/chromedriver doesn't work anymore. The installed chromedriver version doesn't fit to the installed chrome version. I tried to update chromedriver, but without success. When running

`binman::list_versions("chromedriver")`

I get

```
$mac64_m1
[1] "105.0.5195.19" "105.0.5195.52" "106.0.5249.21"
```

The problem is: I don't know why those versions are installed, where they are installed and how I can update them from within binman or wdman .

I followed the installation guide for chromedriver on Mac here https://www.swtestacademy.com/install-chrome-driver-on-mac/ but that didn't change anything. It also didn't add the installed version to the ones being recognised by binman.

When I am using the search function, I can't find any of the chrome drivers that binman identifies, but I can find the version that I downloaded (and moved to library/bin/).

Does anybody know how I can find the directory in which the binman chromedriver versions are installed? How can I install the latest chromedriver or a specific version with binman or wdman? I also tried

```
app_dir("chromedriver", check = TRUE)
```

which doesn't give any results

Best regards

**UPDATE:**

I found the solution.

1. Find the binman_chromedriver directory on your MAC. You can use RStudio for that:

```
appdir <- binman::app_dir("chromedriver", check = TRUE)
appdir
```

2. Open up MAC Terminal and go to the binman_chromedriver directory
3. Within that directory, create a new folder with the name of the chromedriver version you want to install.

```
mkdir 108.0.5359.71
```

4. Go into the new folder

```
cd 108.0.5359.71
```

5. Download the zipped version of chromedriver (copy+paste the link from your browser)

```
curl -O https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/108.0.5359.71/chromedriver_mac_arm64.zip
```

6. Unzip

```
unzip chromedriver_mac_arm64.zip
```

7. go back to RStudio and check the installed versions

```
binman::list_versions("chromedriver")
```

I got

```
$mac64_m1
[1] "105.0.5195.19" "105.0.5195.52" "106.0.5249.21" "108.0.5359.71"
```

And now RSelenium is running again in RStudio on my MAC (and I learned something about moving trough the Terminal ...).

I am pretty sure this has to be done for every new version of Chrome as long as there is no autoupdate from binman.

Comment: This was it ... I spent several hours screwing with it until I found this posting. Evyer just says update your chromedriver, but doesn't say exactly where to place the file. Thank you.